# How do I resolve build error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, react-native-camera

Hey there I was trying to run camera functionality in my react native app so i installed the required libraries but whenever i am trying to run the app it gives me build error. The error is quite long but it says:
(* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':react-native-vision-camera' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30)
Please help me out with this

I am a beginner and tried visiting various react sites and reaching out various youtube videos and editing my file but still the result is zero